# possible paths in a matrix from top left to bottom right

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to find the number of paths from top left to bottom right of matrix (m,n). I also want to store all such possible paths. 
I have solved the number of paths using DP. T:O(m*n), S:O(m*n)
I have also solved finding and storing all the paths; however, here my space complexity is a mess. Roughly: O(max(m,n)^4) ~ O(m^4)/O(n^4) whichever is greater.

I have allocated a 2D array for storing paths. But each element of this array needs to be a list of paths, which is troubling. I have presented my code here which is tested and works. 
Any better solutions?

```
void T(int **&A, vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > **&P, int m, int n) {
    vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > v1, v2;
    vector<pair<int,int> > v11, v22;
    pair<int,int> p1(m-1,0), p2(0,n-1);

    v11.push_back(p1);
    v22.push_back(p2);
    v1.push_back(v11);
    v2.push_back(v22);
    P[m-1][0] = v1;
    P[0][n-1] = v2;
    for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        A[i][0] = 1;
        pair<int,int> pi(i,0);
        if (i != m-1) {
            P[i+1][0][0].insert(P[i+1][0][0].begin(),pi);
            vector<pair<int,int> > tt = P[i+1][0][0];
            vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > kk;
            kk.push_back(tt);
            P[i][0] = kk;
        }
    }
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        A[0][i] = 1;
        pair<int,int> pi(0,i);
        if (i != n-1) {
            P[0][i+1][0].insert(P[0][i+1][0].begin(),pi);
            vector<pair<int,int> > tt = P[0][i+1][0];
            vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > kk;
            kk.push_back(tt);
            P[0][i] = kk;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        A[i][j] = A[i-1][j] + A[i][j-1];
        pair<int,int> pij(i,j);
        vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > vv = P[i-1][j];
        vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > ww = P[i][j-1];

        for (int k = 0; k < vv.size(); k++) {
            vv[k].push_back(pij);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < ww.size(); k++) {
            ww[k].push_back(pij);
            vv.push_back(ww[k]);
        }
        P[i][j] = vv;
    }
}

void PrintPaths(vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > **&P, int m, int n) {
    vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > vv = P[m-1][n-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < vv.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vv[i].size(); j++) {
            cout<<"("<<vv[i][j].first<<","<<vv[i][j].second<<")";
            if (j != vv[i].size()-1)
                cout<<"->";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int m = 2;
    int n = 2;
    int **A = new int*[m];
    vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > **P = new vector<vector<pair<int,int> > >*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        A[i] = new int[n];
        P[i] = new vector<vector<pair<int,int> > >[n];
    }
    T(A,P,m,n);
    PrintPaths(P,m,n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        delete[] A[i];
        delete[] P[i];
    }
    delete[] A;
    delete[] P;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use a trie (prefix tree) to store the paths. For many of those the initial steps are the same.

Comment: if the length is <= 18, you can run a dfs+bitmask otherwhise use a vector to store the paths.

Comment: There are `Choose(n+m,n)` (which is in `O(max{n,m}^min{n,m})`) such paths, storing them all is not trivial

Comment: Could you be convinced that "don't store them" is a better way? If you are after one specific path to min/max some other practical function later, it would probably be better to re-compute it with the same DP approach, and then backtrack to reconstruct the desired path.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering if this problem was to be displayed graphically then one would like to see all possible paths from point A to point B highlighted in different colours. So, yes all paths would be needed.